# Firebase is rejecting some user's email addresses on certain devices

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have an app made with React Native that I started getting active users on yesterday. Most users are able to sign up to the app.

However, two of them are having their email addresses rejected by Firebase. Both of them are using gmail email accounts and they are both using Samsungs.

I was able to create an account for both of them using my own device, without any issues. However, they are still not even able to log in when inputting their email address.

Do you have any idea why some legitimate email addresses that look like something@gmail.com would be getting rejected while most users are having no issues?

Below is the code I am using on the registration screen:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styles from './styles';
// import {firebase} from '../../firebase/config';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export default function RegistrationScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

  const onFooterLinkPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Login');
  };

  const onRegisterPress = async () => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("Passwords don't match.");
      return;
    }
    if (email === '') {
      alert("Please enter an email.")
    }
    else if (password === '') {
      alert("Please enter a password.")
    }
    else if (confirmPassword === '') {
      alert("Please enter the same password in both password fields.")
    }
    else if (password.length < 6) {
      alert("Please enter a password with at least 6 characters.")
    }
    else {
      await auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(async response => {
          const uid = response.user.uid;
          const data = {
            id: uid,
            email,
            // fullName,
          };
          const usersRef = await firestore().collection('users');
          usersRef
            .doc(uid)
            .set(data)
            .then(() => {
              navigation.navigate('Languages Nav');
              // navigation.navigate('Spanish', {additionalUserInfo: data});
            })
            .catch(error => {
              alert("There was an error. Please ensure you have provided the correct details. If you have, send me an email at (email) and I'll fix it.");

              console.log(error.code);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          switch (error.code) {
            case "auth/email-already-in-use":
              alert("That email has already been registered");
            case "auth/invalid-email":
              alert("Please provide a correct email address.");
            default:
              alert("There was an error. Please ensure you have provided the correct details. If you have, send me an email at (email) and I'll fix it.");
              console.log(error.code);
          }

        });
    }

  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="never">
        {/* <Image
          style={styles.logo}
          source={require('../../../assets/icon.png')}
        /> */}
        {/* <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Full Name"
          placeholderTextColor="#969696"
          onChangeText={text => setFullName(text)}
          value={fullName}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        /> */}
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="E-mail"
          placeholderTextColor="#808080"
          onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
          value={email}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholderTextColor="#808080"
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
          value={password}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholderTextColor="#808080"
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
          onChangeText={text => setConfirmPassword(text)}
          value={confirmPassword}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => onRegisterPress()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Create account</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.footerView}>
          <Text style={styles.footerText}>
            Already got an account?{' '}
            <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress} style={styles.footerLink}>
              Log in
            </Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Below is the login screen:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styles from './styles';
// import {firebase} from '../../firebase/config';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export default function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const onFooterLinkPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Registration');
  };
  const onPasswordResetPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('ResetPassword');
  };

  const onLoginPress = () => {
    if (email === '') {
      alert("Please enter an email.")
    }
    if (password === '') {
      alert("Please enter a password.")
    }
    else {
      auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(response => {
          const uid = response.user.uid;
          const usersRef = firestore().collection('users');
          usersRef
            .doc(uid)
            .get()
            .then(firestoreDocument => {
              if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
                alert('That email address and password combination did not match any users.');
                return;
              }
              const user = firestoreDocument.data();
              navigation.navigate('Languages Nav', {
                additionalUserInfo: user,
              });
            })
            .catch(error => {
              alert("That email address and password combination did not match any users.")
              console.log(error.code);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.code);
          alert("That email address and password combination did not match any users.")
        });
    }

  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="never">
        {/* <Image
          style={styles.logo}
          source={require('../../../assets/icon.png')}
        /> */}
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="E-mail"
          placeholderTextColor="#808080"
          onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
          value={email}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholderTextColor="#808080"
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
          value={password}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => onLoginPress()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Log in</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.footerView}>
          <Text style={styles.footerText}>
            Don't have an account?{' '}
            <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress} style={styles.footerLink}>
              Sign up
            </Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footerView}>
          <Text onPress={onPasswordResetPress} style={styles.footerLink}>
            Reset Password
          </Text>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: What does "getting rejected" mean here? What method calls gives what exact error message for what exact value?

Comment: In the registration screen the error the user's are seeing is "There was an error. Please ensure you have provided the correct details. If you have, send me an email at (email) and I'll fix it." and in the login screen they are seeing ""That email address and password combination did not match any users." However, I do not know what error code is causing it since the email addresses are working perfectly fine when I'm testing them. I think it could be an issue with their devices.

Comment: I think .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) and .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) is causing both of the errors. Do you have a suggestion of how I can figure out what the error codes are?

Comment: You'll need to log the error code/message from Firebase and the data that triggers it somewhere where you can look it up and add it to your question. Without those it'll be hard to help beyond the obvious: it looks like the email address they use to sign in is not registered.

Comment: I will go ahead and do that. Thanks.